# Accessing many cells and worksheet cell_range module for Index and Lookup functions using python openpy module

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

How to the fix Ranges of cells using python3 openpy module

Reading an excel file and setup the Ranges of cells, can be accessed using slicing:

```
cell_range = ws['A20':'C20']
```

Answer (score 0):

openpy library for reading and writing Excel ranges of rows or columns can be obtained similarly:
For example:

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import Workbook
filename_bot='sample_test.xlsx'
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=filename_bot)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[1]  # Sheet name
cell_range = ws1['A10':'C10']
for row in cell_range:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.coordinate,  cell.value)
```